# Filter data but keep at least one row for each ID

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

In this example data, I want filter out those rows where `col1` and `col2` are both zeros.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(letters[1:3], each = 2),
  col1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  col2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  col3 = LETTERS[1:6]
)
```

This is what I tried:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(col1 == 1 | col2 == 1)

#   id col1 col2 col3
# 1  a    1    0    A
# 2  a    1    1    B
# 3  c    0    1    E
```

It works fine but all rows where `id` is `"b"` are removed. Are there any ways to keep at least one row for each `id`? My expected output is:

```r
#   id col1 col2 col3
# 1  a    1    0    A
# 2  a    1    1    B
# 3  b   NA   NA    -
# 4  c    0    1    E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete()`:

```r
df %>%
  filter(col1 == 1 | col2 == 1) %>%
  tidyr::complete(id = df$id, fill = list(col3 = "-"))

# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   id     col1  col2 col3 
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1 a         1     0 A    
# 2 a         1     1 B    
# 3 b        NA    NA -    
# 4 c         0     1 E
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer; one little twist one could do is convert id to a factor and use `tidyr::complete(id, fill = list(col3 = "-"))`.

Comment: @Maël You are right! I also think about that. But I want to save the use of an additional `mutate()` line.